# How can I change the PowerShell prompt color?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, powershell-core

I often find myself lost in a plethora of lines all looking the same. It's hard for me to tell the beginning of the output of my most recent commmand from the output of previous commands.

So, I'd like to change the color of my PowerShell prompt permanently from white text on black background to something else. How can I do this?

From my perspective, the prompt consists of two parts:

1. path
2. command

How can I change the color of any of both, but not changing the command's output color?

Alternatively, I'd also very much like to see the path part getting underlined. This would also help in finding my previous commands among lines of other output in order to see where the corresponding other output started. Is this possible?

### EDIT

Some comments requested some elaboration on my question, so here's two screenshots depicting the actual/expected situation (note the red line):

#### actual

[image]

#### expected

[image]

I'd like to get this for PowerShell 5.x and Core.

So, do you think this is rather a feature request than a query for an existing feature?

Comment: You can change the (font) color of the host, whether you can "*change the color of any of both, but not changing the command's output color?*" I am not sure. In any case, it is important to know with version of PowerShell you run. Windows PowerShell, PowerShell Core and which IDE you use (if any).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After posting my question to the PowerShell team at GitHub, here's the answer to my question:

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11136

There's a `prompt()` hook function available that can be used to customize the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

[image: This is the picture of the powershell editor im talking about in my last paragraph]

I found out that if you use Powershell 5.1, you could use some escaping characters from ASCII table in order to get underlined output:

```bsh
Write-Host "Hello $([char]27)[4mWorld$([char]27)[24m"
```

Since Im hesitant that this works perfect, the best solution to underline specific text might be this way:

```bsh
function Write-Underlined-Host([string]$text,[boolean]$ispath)
{
    if ($ispath -eq $false)
    { 
        Write-Host $text
    }
    else
    {
        $underline = '-'
        $underline_count = $underline * $text.Length

        Write-Host -Object $text
        Write-Host -Object $underline_count
    }
}

$my_path = 'c:\users\jime\desktop'

Write-Underlined-Host -text $my_path -ispath $true
```

If you look to change your powershell script editor colors (For example if you use ISE), you could change the color of all types.

In ISE:
Tools>Options>Script Pane Tokens: (See my attached picture)

Comment: All I needed was this line `Write-Host "some text here" -ForegroudColor Yellow`